# How to get return from nested jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function:

```
function query(db, querystr){

    var resultSet;

    db.transaction(function(tx){

        tx.executeSql(querystr, [], function(tx, results){


            console.log("ROWS ---> "+results.rows);

            resultSet = results.rows;

        }, dbError);

    }, dbError, dbSuccess);

    return resultSet;

}
```

How can I get results.rows in the main function so that I can return to the caller?

Suppose a caller does something like:
`var result_rows = query(db, 'select 1 from dual');`

How can I make sure that result_rows gets the results.rows value from tx.executeSql nested function? The way I did in this example the caller gets undefined.

Thank you,
TS

Comment: Like AJAX, Javascript Database is asynchronous, and the function returns before the transaction takes place. You have to do everything in the callback function, not with the return value.

Comment: Can I alter a global variable from within the nested function?

Comment: @T.S. but everyone will tell you not to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. Pass the callback function to the query() function and call it after the executeSql function is executed.

```
function query("ss","querystr" function (data){ 
//data contains  results.rows from query function
});

function query(db, querystr, cb){

    db.transaction(function(tx){

        tx.executeSql(querystr, [], function(tx, results){

            cb(results.rows);
            //console.log("ROWS ---> "+results.rows);

            resultSet = results.rows;

        }, dbError);

    }, dbError, dbSuccess);
}
```

Comment: Perfect... callback function it is. This goes more to what I was looking for. Thanks a lot Sunny!

Answer (score 0):

For starters, Barmar's comment is right: You could never really guarantee the data to come back in the same Javascript thread/stack/whatever you call it, so you can't just return it.

The most common pattern to do something with an asynchronously-retrieved item is that the requesting function should pass in an onSuccess function, to be called, with the resulting data as an argument. This kind of pattern is much better for performance, as the UI thread is not blocked.

```
var pizza = getMeAPizza('pepperoni');
console.log('Yesss, got my pizza.');

//becomes...

getMeAPizza('pepperoni', function(pizza) {
  console.log('Yesss, got my pizza.');
}
```

I think if you're developing a JQuery plugin as you say, from what I understand, one common pattern is to implement the "[Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)" object definition when returning it, so the calling function can chain a following action. This part is second-hand knowledge for me, so I won't bother trying desperately to explain it...